# Proving when Two Bases are Equivalent

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If B,C are two (potentially) distinct bases of a real vector space V, and the transition matrix from $P_{C->B}$ is the identity matrix then $B=C$.

This seems obvious from the definition of transition matrix but I am unsure how to write up a formal proof.

Comment: Arrange you basis columnwisely as a matirx.

Comment: @Solitary So, then B will be $C*P_{C->B}$, which is just C, so the statement follows?